# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when trying to run a FOR with python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I'm getting this error when trying to execute a select function from a CRUD that I'm doing in Python. I'm working on an application that initially had a SQLite3 database and I'm trying to migrate to MySQL for a few reasons. It turns out that in SQLite the application worked perfectly, and now I'm getting this error about a FOR that I'm trying to navigate.

```py
def select_list(self):

        self.list_cli.delete(*self.lista_cli.get_children())

        self.conecting_bd()

        list = self.cursor.execute("""SELECT cod, name_client, phone, city FROM clients

                                    ORDER BY name_client ASC; """)

        for i in list:

            self.list_cli.insert("", END, values=i)

        self.desconect_bd()
```

This same code worked perfectly before changing the database, I didn't make any changes to the Python code specifically, and for that reason I'm not able to find a solution, as I don't really can see the problem. I've searched about it before asking here, but it seems to be a very peculiar error despite TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

When I add a comment at the FOR part of the code it works and I'm able to show up on a tkinter screen all clients data like a spreadsheet.
But that's not what I want. I need the FOR working so I can display the select command which is clients data.

Hope you all might help me!

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: That would happen if the `clients` table were empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `sqlite3` module, `cursor.execute("SELECT ...")` returns a cursor object.

However, for `mysql-connector-python` module, `cursor.execute()` returns `None` no matters there are records returned or not. You need to check the document of the MySQL module you used.

For compatibility, you can iterate the cursor object after execute the SELECT statement:

```py
self.cursor.execute("""SELECT ...""")

for i in self.cursor:
    self.list_cli.insert("", END, values=i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment it totally worked! I used the self.cursor and I'll check on it to understand it better for next times.